# Function to reset a counter to 0 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting to reset a counter to 0. My code is redacted for your easy reading and works. I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to express this (`TotalCount == 0` doesn't work as I had hoped).

What's a more efficient way of expressing the code below in Swift?

```
var TotalCount = Int()

func ResetCounts(){
    if (TotalCount >= 10){
        TotalCount--
        TotalCount--
        TotalCount--
        TotalCount--
        TotalCount--
        TotalCount--
        TotalCount--
        TotalCount--
        TotalCount--
        TotalCount--
    }
    else{
        println("Oops this somehow didn't work")
    }
}
```

Comment: Dammit, why did I think that was ==0.

Answer (score 0):

As Pang mentions

TotalCount = 0

Thought that was executed via TotalCount == 0 for some reason... Derp.

Comment: `=` is the **assignment operator** whereas `==` is a **comparison operator** :)